# Someones elses code seems to be returning a varying ProcessorID

Tags: c++, .net, processor

I support some software by a Japanese vendor. They protect their software using time limited license codes. The code works only for a particular computer using a hardware ID that seems to be created using a few different ID's of PC components.

However on a couple of machines out of approximately 150 sometimes the license stops working because the hardware id has changed.
Now their software tool generates a txt of the hardware components, so i can see the before and after and see what has changed.
Picking only the lines that have changed i can see in one of the files i have...

```
CurrentClockSpeed : 784  
ProcessorId : 178BFBFF00100F63
```

And in the other..

```
CurrentClockSpeed : 2800  
ProcessorId : 078BFBFF00100F63
```

If i convert these processor ID to binary, then i have...

```
  1011110001011111110111111111100000000000100000000111101100011
```

and..

```
  0011110001011111110111111111100000000000100000000111101100011
```

Now i dont have access to their code, and am being told that they think the problem is with the hardware. Someone is overclocking it, or one CPU core is defaulting out, causing the code to pick another core.

(I can imagine different core possibly having a different and adjacent id, but id expect the LSB to be the one to change, not the MSB.)
I remain unconvinced by their explanation. Especially since the id is changing by only 1 bit.

Does this seem to be a Get CPUID call? If so, do different cores have a different ID? Even if they did, would this explain the changing CurrentClockSpeed?

The get CPUID seems to suggest it gives info with regards to whichever core the thread is currently running on. On a 2 core system, could this be effectively random between 1 of 2 values?
Id be very glad of any advice/opinions on this

Answer (score 1):

If that's what you fear is going on, it's fairly trivial to set the affinity of the process to a single core.  That said, one would expect many of their customers to be complaining if you were right - multi core systems have been the standard for many years;  and I'd be very surprised if your system only has 2 cores.  In addition, you'd be seeing this on all your machines.

Ultimately, the group you need to talk to is the supplier, not stack overflow.